# What is spectral flow of electrons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, chirality, weyl-semimetal

While reading about chiral anomaly in condensed matter systems, I came across the term  electron **Spectral flow**. I have no idea what this is and where to look for understanding this. Please help.

Comment: Spectral flow is a concept from mathematics in the context of Fredholm operators and index theory. It does not really have something to do with electrons. However, due to electrons being described by spinors and, hence, a Dirac operator, they are inherently related to this theory.

Comment: Spectral flow is the movement/rearrangement of Hamiltonian eigenvalues (energy levels) as a parameter is varied (a notional "time"). Typically, the net number of eigenvalues crossing zero in a given direction, from above or below, as a background parameter (sphaleron, etc...) varies. Your source does not cover that?

Comment: @CosmasZachos No, I have no idea where to read about this from. Do you have any source suggestions...

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.77.125025